# How can I set the element's inner position fixed to middle of the screen?

Tags: html, css

So how can I set an element's inner position fixed to middle of screen? I was able to set the x-axis of the `div` by using `text-align: center;`.

So how could I center the y-axis just like I did the x-axis? And if *that* can't be done, what new method must I use?

**Code**:

```css
.fixed{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 99;
}

.popup{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 900px;
    min-height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.4);
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="popup"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle. Just make your popup class position fix and make top,left,bottom,right = 0 then margin:auto. See this updated fiddle.

```
.popup{
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   margin:auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/norxpmbr/

Answer (score 0):

For `.popup`, try replacing this:

```
margin-bottom: 50px;
margin-top: 20px;
```

With this:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Source: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did to your code- removed the margins for `popup` and centered using `transform` and `position: relative`:

```
    .popup{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 90%;
      max-width: 900px;
      min-height: 300px;
      border: 2px solid rgba(72,72,72,0.4);
      margin    : 0;
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a7sv9g25/)

Snippet below:

```css
.fixed {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 99;
}
.popup {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.4);
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="popup">
  </div>
</div>
```